How to undo LinuxScoop's "macOS look alike" (WhiteSur theme etc.) customization process ? (Ubuntu 24.04)
After customizing Ubuntu with regular extensions (tweaks, etc.), I was curious to push things further and see how it would look like and work with a macOS lookalike theme (WhiteSur). I was actually only interested in the colored windows buttons and thought I could drop the other aspects of the theme/customization.
I followed this tutorial step by step : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cueqrwlBv6M&ab_channel=LinuxScoop
I can rewrite the whole customization process if needed.
To sum up, I cloned the WhiteSur theme from github with the Terminal, including icons and cursors which were then copied into $HOME/.icons directory that had to be created.
Also installed Cava, Neofetch, zsh, Flatpak... in the process.
After installing Plymouth theme (sudo apt install plymouth -y) by extracting plymouth-theme.zip into /usr/share/plymouth/themes directory [sudo unzip -o $HOME/Downloads/plymouth-theme.zip -d /usr/share/plymouth/themes], I applied GNOME Shell settings on Ubuntu with the following commands :
unzip $HOME/Downloads/ubuntu2404-gnome46-macos-config.zip -d $HOME/Downloads 

The macOS layout applied to my Ubuntu desktop after the next following command :
dconf load / < $HOME/Downloads/gnome46-macos-ubuntu2404.conf 

Turns out I don't like it at all. Moreover, it messed up my dock, my keyboard (fixed in the mean time), my other regular tweaks extensions, my preferences... It's confusing and seems to slow down my computer. Moreover, I can't seem to go back to Ubuntu GNOME desktop/theme configuration in the settings or extensions manager.
I would like to undo the whole process properly without messing up with the system or my files and getting back to Ubuntu's regular theme and desktop options (including with tweaks and extensions I already implemented before trying this "macOS customization").
Many thanks for your help !

Change the theme back, revert back to the default plymouth theme, remove cava, neofetch, etc...

Hi @ArchismanPanigrahi , thank you for your response. I'm sorry but could you give me a little more insight on how to do this step by step ? I'm not sure of the commands on how to do this without messing up the theme even more. Moreover I'm having issues with the mouse now...

If you are having issues with even the mouse, I suggest you reinstall Ubuntu.
